Error as NetLogo is trying to compare 30 lists and make an edge if correlation is greater than 0.5
Once trying to compare 30 lists and make an edge, if correlation is greater than 0.5, an error was detected at
foreach stock-prices [ prices1 i ]

saying

expecting anonymous command rather than list, block

stock-prices  ; A list of lists, where each sub-list contains the price data for one stock
correlations  ; A matrix to store correlation coefficients

to compute-correlations
  ;                    Initialize the correlations matrix with zeros
  set correlations (list (map [ -> n-values 30 [ 0 ] ] range 30))
  
  ;                    Compute the correlation for each pair of stocks
  foreach stock-prices [prices1 i] [
    foreach stock-prices [prices2 j] [
      if i != j [
        let corr correlation-coefficient prices1 prices2
        set correlations replace-item i correlations replace-item j (item j (item i correlations)) corr
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to draw-edges
  ask turtles [
    let my-id stock-id
    ask turtles with [stock-id > my-id] [
      if item stock-id (item my-id correlations) > 0.5 [
        create-link-with myself
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to-report correlation-coefficient [prices1 prices2]
  let n length prices1
  let mean1 mean prices1
  let mean2 mean prices2
  let stddev1 standard-deviation prices1
  let stddev2 standard-deviation prices2
  let covariance mean (map [ (item ? prices1 - mean1) * (item ? prices2 - mean2) ] n-values n [ ? ])
  report covariance / (stddev1 * stddev2)
end


Welcome to StackOverflow - you might notice the posted source code is inconsistent indents with the Community rules. Could you revise your code, so as to indeed meet the MCVE-standard? M-inimum + C-omplete ( to run, ie with any data files needed to load too ) + V-erfiable E-xample showing what the problem is ( so it runs into the error-message you claim - so it practically self-manifests both the running problem & the collision you try to solve ) - that is the Community best-practice here + that's fair, isn't it?

I can definitely answer your question about the correct syntax to use if I understand your intention.  But it took me a bit of puzzling, in order to figure out what I think you're trying to do.  So, when you write foreach stock-prices [ prices1 i ] [ ... ], am I right in thinking that you want to iterate over stock-prices, referring to current index in stock-prices as i and the item at the ith index as prices1, in the block of code [ ... ]?  If that's right, then I think this is the code that you want:

let indices (range length stock-prices) 

foreach indices [
  i ->
    foreach indices [
      j ->
        if i != j [
          let prices1 (item i stock-prices)
          let prices2 (item j stock-prices)
          let corr correlation-coefficient prices1 prices2
          set correlations replace-item i correlations replace-item j (item j (item i correlations)) corr
        ]
    ]
]

